# Proof that if a complex sequence ($x_k$) converges to $a$ if and only if $a$ is an accumulation point of every subsequence of $x_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Can someone help me with the question in the title?

I know how to proof the direction from left to right, but not the other way.

My idea was to do a contraposition in the following way:
Assume ($x_k$) is not converging to $a$. Then from definition there exist a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ which does not include "almost all sequence points". This means that there are infinitely many elements outside of $U$. Now I want to somehow construct a subsequence which does not have $a$ as an accumulation point and thus not all subsequences have $a$ as an accumulation point and the proof is done. But I am not sure how to continue.

Greetings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\{x_n\}$ converges to $a$, then $\forall\varepsilon>0$, $\exists n_0\in\mathbb N$, such that
$$ 
\forall n\ge n_0 \quad\Longrightarrow\quad |x_n-a|<\varepsilon.
$$

If $\{x_n\}$ DOES NOT converge to $a$, then
$\exists\varepsilon>0$, such that $\forall n_0\in\mathbb N$,
$$ 
\exists n\ge n_0 \quad\text{\&}\quad |x_n-a|\ge\varepsilon.
$$
This is equivalent to: *There exists a $\varepsilon>0$, such that the set*
$$
S=\{n\in\mathbb N: |x_n-a|\ge \varepsilon\}
$$
*is infinite.*

Since $S$ is infinite, then we can write the elements of $S$ as a strictly increasing sequence:
$$
S=\{k_1<k_2<\cdots<k_n<k_{n+1}<\cdots\}
$$
In particular, $k_1=\min S$ and recursively, $k_{n+1}=\min S\setminus\{k_1,\ldots,k_n\}$

Now the subsequence $\{x_{k_n}\}$ does not converge to $a$, since
$$
|x_{k_n}-a|\ge\varepsilon, \quad\text{for all $n\in\mathbb N$}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! Why can we write the elements of $S$ as a strictly increasing sequence if $S$ is infinite?

Comment: The strictly sequence is defined recursively. First term the smallest element of $S$, i.e., $k_1=\min S$. Second term the second smallest, $k_2=\min S\setminus\{k_1\}$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

If you *don't* have $\lim_{k\to\infty}x_k=a$, then, for some $\varepsilon>0$, there are infinitely many $k$'s such that $|x_k-a|\geqslant\varepsilon$. Take a sequence $(x_{k_n})_{n\in\Bbb N}$ of such $x_k$'s, and that will give a subsequence of $(x_k)_{k\in\Bbb N}$ of which $a$ is not an accumulation point.

Comment: Great. I was thinking in the same direction, but could not think of defining such a subsequence. I think Yiorgos made it clear to me how to construct it.

Comment: The construction is easy: $k_1$ is the first $k$ such that $|x_k-a|\geqslant\varepsilon$, $k_2$ is the second $k$ such that $|x_k-a|\geqslant\varepsilon$, and so on. Then $\left(x_{k_n}\right)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is the subsequence that you're after.